# How can I update hook without creating a new listener?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created my own custom hook that listens for updates from a server. The problem I am facing is that `groups` can also be `null`, so I need to check it. Therefore, I need it as part of my dependencies so the `useEffect` can update when `groups` does, but that also leads to creating multiple listeners, which I don't want. Thanks in advance :).

```js
export function useStatusListener(groups, setGroups) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = appRuntime.subscribe(
            "channel-name",
            (args) => {
                if (groups) {
                    // more code here...
                }
            }
        );

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, [groups]);
}
```

Comment: You're not creating multiple listeners as each one unsubscribes in an `useEffect` cleanup function when the `groups` value updates. This looks fine to me. Is there an issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I guess that's true. Is there any way that I can use the same listener instead of creating new ones, since I am calling the `setGroups` where it says `more code here...`, which updates the `groups` and causes the listener to be replaced on every event?

Comment: I see. Using a React ref for accessing a cached. version of state in any event listeners. Can you update your question to include a bit more if what the "more code here" is doing? The goal is to remove dependencies and only instantiate 1 listener when the component mounts. Or change/add the condition so you aren't creating a render loop by updating the `groups` dependency.